# Prevent PDF form modification

Tags: pdf, qpdf

I am likely misunderstanding the concept here, but my case is this:

1. I have a received a PDF with editable fields / form that I have filled.
2. I want to lock it so that it can't be changed, but still read.

I use [`qpdf` Encryption feature](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#encryption)

Have tried various things like:

```
qpdf --encrypt "" password 256 --annotate=n --form=n -- input.pdf locked.pdf
qpdf --encrypt "" password 256 --modify=none -- input.pdf locked.pdf
```

These leaves the document open for modification.

Does `qpdf` or similar have an option to do what I want?

Comment: why use a `qpdf` tag if you do not know that it can do the job? ... your question is more suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Both commands work fine here (`qpdf` 11.2.0): they produce a "locked" pdf  i.e. I can no longer edit/modify the forms in the output file (more precisely, clicking "show forms" in `okular`  highlights them but they are not editable)

Comment: @don_crissti Hmm ... opening it in `okular` it is locked indeed. Did not use that, I used `qpdfview` and also checked in Firefox – there I can edit. Looks like the viewer might be the issue, i.e. they do not honor protected status - which in essence makes the feature rather useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've filled in the form with a PDF viewer, you can simply print it out to a PDF printer as a new file. This flattens it so the content can't be changed w/o a PDF editor.

Alternatively you can fill the form in a PDF editor and configure the permissions so that it can be viewed but not edited w/o a password; then export / print a new PDF.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I did, but hoped there was a "lock" feature so that one could "unlock" it later if needed. From comment under question it looks like the encryption is not honored by many viewers, - which makes it useless. If it worked as I thought, one could lock a "flattened" PDF as well and prevent it to be modified, prevent printing etc.

Comment: I don't see value in preventing printing of the form, but locking it to prevent modification would be a good addition to PDF reader capabilities. Nothing's unbreakable tho'. Password crackers exist. You could screenshot the filled in form and add the images to a word processor file; or print it out and scan it in as new PDF, but even those can be OCR:d which will render the text editable again. Security is always a question of making breaking it hard enuff that it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Sure. One could circumvent print by simply screenshots (unless one are using CIA/NSA like platforms as Wayland) where one could use cellphone to shoot pics instead of course – but for one: One can not *inadvertently* fuck it up w/o an effort, the hint is strong, two: it (might/likely) make indexing harder by engines if some tard posts it. It's more of a "OK, you can of course circumvent this, but you have to make an effort, and if someone have missed the note". Secondly it is a low level "dumb filter". (Dumb not always being **dumb** person etc.,- but also uninformed.)

Comment: Not really. OCR doesn't care how the image is created. It works surprisingly well even with very low-quality images. However, that's exactly it - how much effort is it sensible to put in to modify the form. With all the PDF forms I've ever encountered, the answer is categorically "not very much" :-)

Comment: The landscape has surely changed over the years, - but I often deal with people that have little to none idea of doing what you say. I.e. *the average person*. Sure they can ask the office wizard – but it still is a *“hey, should you do this?”*

Comment: LOL tell me abt it. I tend to revert to parallels like "You can prepare rice in a watercooker, but should you?" :-D